# Load random js file on page load or refresh

Tags: javascript, html

please help me, can i load a random javascript file tagged in html? I know this is possible with css, but I want to try with javascript. Or at least show javascript code sometimes yes sometimes no.

For example, i have two javascript files named **"1.js"** and **"2.js"**. How i can tag one per page load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this code will randomly load a JavaScript file when the page loads.
it will pick a file randomly in the list JSFiles,
 and append the JS file to the *head* section.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Load Random JS file</title>
</head>
<script>
 var JSFiles = ['1.js','2.js']; // put all the possible JS files to load.
 function randomJS() {
     // pick a random file from the list in JSFiles
     var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*JSFiles.length); 

     // Append JS file to head section.
     var script = document.createElement('script');
     script.src = JSFiles[index];
     document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
 };
</script>
<body onload="randomJS();">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would combine the JS file into one file. And create a bunch of Random functions and do them when the file is loaded.

```
//random.js
var array_of_random_function = [function(){
//do something
},
function(){
//do something else
}]
//generate random number as per the length of the above array.
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*array_of_random_function.length); 
array_of_random_function[i]();
```

Comment: The question is about *loading random files*, not how to combine them into one file.

Comment: True, but this is a better way to manage code and keep it modular.

Comment: But you still haven't **answered the actual question**. If you want to suggest an alternative way of solving the problem then add a comment to the question. Your answer will be seen by people who come from search engines, and this will not be very helpful to them.